# Read a string from a file and search that string in another file and write output

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

i have a requirement where i have file1 has below strings:

**file1:**

```
abcd
defg
ijkl
mnop
```

have to read each string from file1 and search in file2 if found print that string as its already exist in file2 and make a output.txt with non match strings from file1

**file2:**

```
zxkn
pxqwl
ijkl
qrst
zvnq
```

**output.txt**

```
abcd
defg
mnop
```

tried:

```
pattern=`tr ',' '|' < "file1.txt"`
tr ',' '\n' < "file2.txt" | egrep "$pattern"
```

Comment: [`comm -23`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) ??

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
grep -v -f file2.txt file1.txt > output.txt
```

-v: return lines without pattern

-f: use lines in file2.txt as input for patterns for grep

Comment: not working in this case,file 1 has a line xabcd and its tottaly ignoring that

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Even though you failed to mention the ```xabcd``` string in your example, it still works. Just tested here.

Comment: grep -v -w -f ile2.txt file1.txt > output.txt--worked for me. with -v an -f if the string is a substring of a pattern then that pattern is getting skipped ..lets suppose file1 has xabcd and file2 has abcd its still giving the match